# Expected time to get from bottom left to top right in a square

Tags: asymptotics, random-walk

Consider a two dimensional random walk starting at the bottom left hand corner of an $n$ by $n$ square. At each step you take one step up, down, left or right distance $1$. Each choice has equal and independent probability of $1/4$. The only exception is if the $x$ or $y$ coordinate is $0$ or $n$, that is you are touching a wall of the square. As you never walk outside the square, if you are touching a wall you choose from the available options again with equal probability.

> What is the expected time to reach the top right hand corner of the
>   square asymptotic to?

Intuitively it seems that it should take something like $n^3$ time asymptotically but I don't know how to derive this mathematically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By symmetry, this is $\frac12C_n$ where $C_n$ denotes the commute time between two opposite corners of the discrete square of size $n\times n$. Exact asymptotics of $C_n$ when $n\to\infty$ might be unknown but, for every graph, the commute time $C_{uv}$ between some vertices $u$ and $v$ is $$C_{uv}=2mR_{uv},$$ where $m$ is the total number of edges and $R_{uv}$ the effective resistance between $u$ and $v$. Also, $R_{uv}\leqslant L_{uv}$ where $L_{uv}$ is the length of the shortest path from $u$ to $v$.
In the present case $m=2n^2$ and $L_{uv}=2n$ hence $$C_n\leqslant8n^3.$$ On the other hand, for every graph on $k$ vertices, $C_{u,v}\geqslant k\log k\,(1+o(1))$ hence, in the present case, $$C_n\geqslant2n^2\log n\,(1+o(1)).$$
For this and much more, see *Random walks on graphs: a survey* by László Lovász.

**Edit:** A careful analysis of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the associated Laplacian (see [there](http://books.google.fr/books?id=QGBGt6J5K4UC&pg=PA243&sa=X&ei=7LIKVPfqF8zbaIjmgfAJ&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBg#v=onepage)) shows that, for every $n$, the effective resistance $R_n$ between two opposite corners of the square lattice of size $n\times n$ is such that $$R_n\lt6+4\log n,$$ hence $$C_n\leqslant16n^2\log n+O(n^2).$$

Comment: Thank you. My intuition for why it should be like $n^3$ was that the $L_1$ distance from the start changes like a symmetric random walk (until you hit a wall).  So you expect to be (roughly) radius $n$ away from the start after (roughly) $n^2$ steps. But then you can be in any of $2n$ places and you only want one of those.

Comment: The correct order is actually $n^2\log n$, see Edit. The $n^3$ heuristics might apply to the hitting time of the middle of a side starting from the middle of the opposite side.

Comment: Can you give any intuition for why it might be much quicker to get to the opposite corner than to some point in the middle of the side? This isn't obvious to me.

Comment: The idea I had in mind was that "at the beginning" one escapes from (0,0) more quickly.